# Generate same action on different web pages

Tags: javascript, web, multiple-instances

I have [a website that, when a user clicks a button, opens an identical site](https://progettazionemauro.github.io/helloclick/). Now, when I type into an `<input>` on that page and then click the button, a new page, that is identical to the first page, is opened with an empty `<input>`.

How I can transfer the value of the input from one page to a new one? In other words, is it possible to programmatically replicate an action from the first page on another page, possibly via javascript?

Comment: If you'd like help with existing code, please include the code here on Stack Overflow, not on an external site that may change. See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: can you show us the code you used to generate the new page

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, I do really suggest you to take a read at the articles that Heretic Monkey suggested to you. Since that will help your question be well-received by the community.

Comment: This is github repo for the code https://github.com/progettazionemauro/helloclick_1.git

Answer (score 0):

You should probably reformat your question, but the answer to your question is **no** . The only way would be to do so programmatically, as in have conditions in your code and somehow store the state of the previous page in a database, or pass information about the previous state using `?parameters`.

The internet itself does not work in the way you describe. There are ways to *simulate* this behavior of course, but that's where you...the programmer come into play.

You can of course pass parameters through the url like:
 `www.example.com/app?someParameter=100` and make some set of decisions when the page loads up based on the value of this parameter...but again, you would have to do this programatically.

Answer (score 0):

you can store value(s) in local storage.

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");

// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```